# PHP/cURL REST 401 / Message Failed

Tags: php, curl

Okay so I get this error:

```
{"Code":401,
"Errors":[{
"Message":"Web request to 'http:\/\/silverstagingapi.ncrsmblab.com\/oauth2authorizationserver\/OAuth2\/Token' failed."}],
"GUID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"IsSuccessful":false,
"Message":"Web request to 'http:\/\/silverstagingapi.ncrsmblab.com\/oauth2authorizationserver\/OAuth2\/Token' failed.",
"Result":null}
```

IT SHOULD look like this:

```
{ "Code": 200, 
"Errors": [], 
"GUID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
"IsSuccessful": true, 
"Message": null, 
"Result": { 
"AccessToken": "gAAAACDf3PAniQx1BqJ8qKZVlTQEP7JpvOYglvk8dsBV80mWxtmRCHc1CouejnKbsXEgYbOLXjN7rdZo-Bz535wdulxgkxRTmnEBTSgdZo-DkBHrp-HeiwjlBt_uSIhH7IdIr5dU0w4M_6KgUBI5e1_GWClDHvZY8R5GQahkpy24TGAp9AAAAIAAAAA11W-Eg", 
"AccessTokenExpirationUtc": "/Date(1445616318650)/", 
"AccessTokenIssueDateUtc": "/Date(1445612718666)/", 
"Callback": null, 
"RefreshToken": null, 
"Scope": [ "APIUSER" ] } }
```

http://pastebin.com/Ryje2B8H

StackOverflow keeps saying the code is unformatted despite Ctrl+K and code tags so I linked to a syntax-highlighted pastebin. The fact I get a JSON Response means the API is functioning / responding. But it doesn't give me anything but a 401 to go off of. I tried fsockopen() before trying curl and it flat out refused the connection. Using cURL I get a response but it fails regardless.

Comment: SO works just fine with Chrome. Using it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The API was limited to 3 specific software partners so it doesn't matter what keys/secrets/data I have. The API only accepts requests from specific domains or vendors it seems.